# SQLAzure database server - named pipes provider, error: 40 - the network path was not found

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

[image]

We access our database that is in SQL Azure, and every so often we hit this error while trying to connect. We connect from a corporate network, using SSMS or API.

The weird part is how it always successfully and instantly connects  on retrying. We retry just 1 second after and it works.

We saw that the DTU Usage % was high and scaled our server up, but that did not help. We have employed a SqlAzureRetry policy while accessing the database from our API, which seems to be helping in mitigating the issue - but the root cause is still not identified.

Has anyone employed a configuration or strategy or faced a similar issue? (the underlying provider failed to open / network path not found).

Thanks!

Comment: You need to check if the application is being throttled. that is when there is too much traffic from similar endpoints to a particular azure resource azure may throttle the requests thinking it might be a possible DDOS attack or it could be a limitation of the type of SaaS product you are using which in this case is azure sql db. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-general-limitations/#cc  http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1541.windows-azure-sql-database-connection-management.aspx#Reasons you can then revisit your design/ setup..

Comment: That theory does not fit the behavior being observed that it immediately connects on the second connection attempt. There is no application as such, just the connection to the database. There maybe throttling  built in to the sql azure architecture to prevent DDOS attacks, but we send only one request from one IP (attempt to connect from SSMS from dev machine) and this cannot be flagged for DDOS.

Comment: .it does. throttling is such where not all connections get through. DDOS is one category. there are multiple throttling cases.as a test you can try upgrading to higher tier of sql azure if you have not tried it already. also since you mentioned corp network it is possibility some outbound requests are blocked/dropped by the corp firewall.

Comment: We have upgraded to a higher pricing tier, as I mentioned in my original question. That doubled our DTU  capacity. But we still have the same issue.

Comment: Is there any packet loss between your client and the Azure SQL instance? You can test with `tcping` on Windows (http://www.elifulkerson.com/projects/tcping.php) and `tcpping` (apt-get install tcptraceroute) on Debians.

Comment: I did tcping -n 100 (ping 100 times). All 100 successful , no packet loss.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution was to change the format of the server name to use TCP:

> tcp:servername.database.windows.net,1433;

Also, if you're connecting from code, you should change to the above format in your connection string.